# Selenium- page source not changing after performing click()

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am scraping this website: https://www.findinall.com/finance-category-396

I am using Selenium(Python) and performing a click option on the option 300 in the dropdown menu named "*Showing*". The click is automated successfully and the webpage shows the entire data in the 12 pages collectively in one page, but after scraping the data, only the first 12 data items are obtained, i.e. page_source doesn't change.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome("/home/ronith/Downloads/chromedriver")

driver.get('https://www.findinall.com/finance-category-396/#')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='per_page']/option[@value  
='300']").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
data=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="pro-list-tb mt15"]')
for i in range(len(data)):
   print(data[i].text,'\n\n')
driver.close()
```

I want to scrape the entire data which is available after the click action is performed. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Learning the difference between `implicit wait` and `explicit wait` would help you to solve the problem. You are populating your `data` list before the page has had the chance to refresh with all 300 records. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather using Selenium to scrape use BeautifulSoup, requests and import the below code

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()
```

and import this code in another python file like this from jssoup import Page (I have named it as 'jssoup')

```
page = Page(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'lxml')
js_test = soup.find('p', class_='jstest')
print(js_test)
```

Comment: I'm using Selenium to automate the button click, otherwise I would have used BeautifulSoup only